# MKAnnotation shows default pin instead of own Image, tried everything

Tags: objective-c, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I would like to use my own Image vor the Annotations i have in my Map. But I only get the default pins.

Here is my     mapView:ForAnnotation:   Method

```
  MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlayerLocation class]]){
   PlayerLocation* annotation2 = (PlayerLocation*)annotation;
    static NSString *identifier = @"MyView";   
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [mapV dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }


    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MKAnnotation" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage* im = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    annotationView.image= im;

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    //delete the flagged Locations
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(deletePin:) withObject:annotation2.name waitUntilDone:NO];
}
return annotationView;
```

I can´t find what is wrong with it. The Image is found an not nil.The delegate is set.The protocol is there , the method gets called.

Here is the whole code involved in adding the annotations. "drawGamers" is the entry point and gets called by the networkhandling class.

```
-(void)drawGamers:(NSMutableArray*)locations{

    for(PlayerLocation* loc in locations ){
        [ self replacePin:loc.name withLocation:loc.coordinate];
    }

}

-(void)replacePin:(NSString *)gamerName  withLocation:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location {
    // flag Location for deletion later
    for (PlayerLocation* annotation in _mapView.annotations){
        if ([annotation.name isEqualToString:gamerName])
            annotation.decomission = YES;
    }
    //add new Location
    PlayerLocation *pLoc = nil;
    pLoc = [[PlayerLocation alloc] initWithName:gamerName address:nil coordinate:location];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:pLoc];
}



- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlayerLocation class]]){
       PlayerLocation* annotation2 = (PlayerLocation*)annotation;
        static NSString *identifier = @"MyView";   
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *) [mapV dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }


        NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MKAnnotation" ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage* im = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

        annotationView.image= im;

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        //delete the flagged Locations
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(deletePin:) withObject:annotation2.name waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
    return annotationView;
}

-(void)deletePin:(NSString *)stationCode{
    for (PlayerLocation *annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
        if ([annotation.name isEqualToString:stationCode]){  
            if (annotation.decomission==YES)
            [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find where the problem is.

Comment: whether you set mapview delegate

Answer (score 0):

In `viewForAnnotation`, the `annotationView` variable is declared twice.

First at the top and then again inside the `if`.  So the setting inside the `if` has no effect on the variable declared outside.

The `return` is done on the outside variable which stays `nil`.

Don't re-declare the variable inside the `if` -- just set it.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapingView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {

     MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[PlayerLocation class]])
    {
         PlayerLocation* annotation2 = (PlayerLocation*)annotation;
         static NSString *identifier = @"MyView";   

         annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];


         NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MKAnnotation" ofType:@"png"];
         UIImage* im = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

         annotationView.image= im;//you can set your image here.

         annotationView.enabled = YES;
         annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
         //delete the flagged Locations
         [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(deletePin:) withObject:annotation2.name waitUntilDone:NO];
     }
return annotationView;
```

}

```
-(void)deletePin:(NSString *)stationCode{
    for (PlayerLocation *annotation in _mapView.annotations) {
        if ([annotation.name isEqualToString:stationCode]){  
            if (annotation.decomission==YES)
            [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }
}
```

This may help you in solving your problem.